# How do I get the timezone with "User's timezone" setting?

Tags: datetime

In Drupal 7 if you set a date field's time zone handling option to "Date's time zone", you get a Timezone selection when entering a date but the date is always displayed in that timezone. If you set the timezone handling option to "User's time zone", you don't get to pick the timezone but the date is displayed according to the user's time zone.

I want to do both. I want content creators to be able to pick a time zone when entering a date and I want that date to be displayed in the user's timezone.

Is that possible with normal configuration options? If not, what hooks should I use?